# Return a value from inside an array that is inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
//Structure
const definitions = {
  sections: [
    { title: 'Section A', actions: [ { id: 0, name: 'action A' } ] },
    { title: 'Section B', actions: [ { id: 1, name: 'action B' } ] },
  ]
};

//Code to retrieve the action    
const id = 1;
const sectionDef = definitions.sections.find(s => s.actions.find(a => a.id === id));
const actionDef = sectionDef.actions.find(a => a.id === id);

//Print it    
console.log(actionDef);
```

The above solution works, but I think there must be a better way to retrieve an object from inside an array especially since I need to run the same code twice...

Comment: `definitions` is an object. I'm not sure how you are executing `find()` method on it. This methods iterates over arrays only.

Comment: @MohammadUsman, code is altered, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an `Array.forEach` and an `Array.find`

```js
//Structure
const definitions = {
  sections: [
    { title: 'Section A', actions: [ { id: 0, name: 'action A' } ] },
    { title: 'Section B', actions: [ { id: 1, name: 'action B' } ] },
  ]
};

//Code to retrieve the action    
const id = 1;
let action;
definitions.sections.forEach(section => {
  action = section.actions.find(a => a.id === id);
});

//Print it    
console.log(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive approach by using all values of the object for searching in an arbitrary data structure.

```js
function find(object, key, value) {
    var result;

    if (object[key] === value) {
        return object;
    }
    if (object && typeof object === 'object') {
        Object.values(object).some(o => result = find(o, key, value));
    }
    return result;
}

var definitions = { sections: [{ title: 'Section A', actions: [{ id: 0, name: 'action A' }] }, { title: 'Section B', actions: [{ id: 1, name: 'action B' }] }] };

console.log(find(definitions, 'id', 0));
console.log(find(definitions, 'id', 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an error on `const sectionDef = definitions.find`, as it should be `const sectionDef = definitions.sections.find` as `find` works for array type. And the way you are doing is fine to achieve the desired result.

```js
const definitions = {
  sections: [
    { title: 'Section A', actions: [ { id: 0, name: 'action A' } ] },
    { title: 'Section B', actions: [ { id: 1, name: 'action B' } ] },
  ]
}

const id = 1;
const sectionDef = definitions.sections.find(s => s.actions.find(a => a.id === id));
const actionDef = sectionDef.actions.find(a => a.id === id);

console.log(sectionDef);
console.log(actionDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const definitions = {
  sections: [
    { title: 'Section A', actions: [ { id: 0, name: 'action A' } ] },
    { title: 'Section B', actions: [ { id: 1, name: 'action B' } ] },
  ]
}
const id = 1;
var result2;
var data = definitions.sections;
var result = data.filter(function(obj) {
    var data2 = obj.actions;
    result2 = data2.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id == id;
    });
});
console.log(result2);
```